# How to add `select count` as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has `invite_code` and `invited_by` columns.

I would like to select all users and the number of users that are invited by this user. Could this be done in one query?

e.g. I have these data:

```
id | invite_code | invited_by   
-----------------------------     
1  |          11 | 
2  |          22 |        11
3  |          33 |        11
4  |          44 |        22
```

I would like to add a `select count(*) from users where u.invite_code = invited_by` to the result:

```
id | invite_code | invited_by | invite_num
------------------------------------------
1  |          11 |            |         2
2  |          22 |         11 |         1
3  |          33 |         11 |         0
4  |          44 |         22 |         0
```

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[InvCode]
      ,[InvBy], (select count(*) from table t where t.[InvBy]=t1.[InvCode])
  FROM table  t1
```

Comment: Sure :) happy to help, if you can Mark my post as an answer it will be great ^^ (click on the V)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join too instead of the subquery in the column list:

```
select u1.id, u1.invite_code, u1.invited_by, u2.invite_num
from users u1
left join (select invited_by, count(*) as invite_num from users group by invited_by) u2
     on u1.invite_code = u2.invited_by;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is with a self-join:

```
select u.id, u.invite_code, u.invited_by, count(u2.id) as invite_num
from user u
left outer join user u2 on u2.invited_by = u.invite_code
group by u.id, u.invite_code, u.invited_by
```

Comment: This is what I am waiting for before set the answer. Thanks!